# how to make react-monaco-edtor responsive?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, monaco-editor

I am using react-monaco-editor but I am not able to make it responsive. It takes a fixed height and width in the components. If I change the screen size, the width stays fixed.

```
    <MonacoEditor
      width="1200"
      height="600"
      language="typescript"
      theme="vs-dark"
      defaultValue="//type your code here"
      value={code}
      options={options}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      editorDidMount={this.editorDidMount}
      className='editor1'
    />
```

If I remove the width and height from the component, the component diminishes. I tried overriding the component className with flex. But it doesn't seem to work well.

```
.react-monaco-editor-container {
   flex: 2;
}
```

Can you help me with the CSS to make this responsive?

Comment: [monaco-react](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react) seems to work much better with Create-React-App. It's responsive by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few things didn't work with CSS, I tried javascript to solve this

```
  updateDimensions = () => {
    this.setState({
      width: window.innerWidth - 501,
      height: window.innerHeight - 50,
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }
```

Storing the `height` and `width` in the state and changing on `resize` event did the job.

Comment: Note: this is only a partial solution. It works only when the window is resized. But if the editor is embedded in a resizable element and that is resized, the editor will not update properly. Check `ResizeObserver` for a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

Simply in `options` set `automaticLayout: true`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a resize handler in order to figure out the available space for your editor container and pass it to your Monaco Editor right away.

There are as well different libraries that assist you with that:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-resize-detector

Here you can find a Sandbox example with using the library above:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-goldwasser-3d8j7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import React from "react";
import { withResizeDetector } from "react-resize-detector";

const Editor = ({ width, height }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      background: "grey",
      height: height,
      width: width
    }}
  >
    Editor container with {width} x {height}
  </div>
);

export default withResizeDetector(Editor);
```

Comment: tried this as well now. Still it doesn't make it responsive